# Paraphrase (not define) the word "psychedelic"?

Tags: word-meaning

> NEW YORK — Perry Ellis is not a brand that makes men nervous or causes them to titter. Even if a work-a-day guy doesn’t wear Perry Ellis clothes, he probably recognizes the name from those times he has wandered through a department store looking to stock up on dress shirts. Perry Ellis is not niche; it is mass. And its creative director, Michael Maccari designed a spring 2016 collection that was welcoming to a wide swath of men. Board shorts, crewneck sweaters, lean — but not tight — suits. Rich colors but nothing too **psychedelic**.

Could you paraphrase (not define) the word "psychedelic", here, please?

Comment: Some examples from [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=psychedelic+colors&biw=1136&bih=769&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI557iosTjxgIVDC6ICh3dGAp_)

Answer (score 2):

(Paraphrase.)  "Rich colors but nothing too crazy."

Answer (score 1):

(Paraphrase) "Rich colors, but nothing too trippy."

(Paraphrase) "Rich colors, but no flashbacks to the '60s."

Answer (score 1):

Rich colors, but no day-glo brights, nor mind-boggling, dizzying patterns.